# Product Creation in Magento 2 by SOAP API

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I am able to create Product in magento 2 by using SOAP API but not able to add quntity , Category for simple product and not able to add simple products to configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

Quantity is created via another API. You should use `catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1` to add stock for your product.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1

Note: Although I'm citing REST API source, you can use it on SOAP too.

Comment: thanks for help. But they list all REST API's but i need SOAP API

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html

Comment: i am tried "configurableProductLinkManagementV1" to add simple product to configurable product but i am getting "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'childSku' property in vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php:1116" error

Comment: This is another question, you can ask a separate question for it.

Comment: i posted new question for this. Link is https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206837/add-simple-product-to-configurable-product-in-magento-2-by-soap-api