# Add simple product to configurable product in Magento 2 by SOAP API

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I am tried "**configurableProductLinkManagementV1**" to add simple product to configurable product.

```
$result = $soapClient->configurableProductLinkManagementV1addChild(
arr‌​ay('sku' => 'sampleconfigurable','childsku'=>'samplesimpleproduct'));
```

But, I am getting

> **PHP Fatal error**: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'childSku' property in
>   vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php:1116

=========================================================

```
<?php
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');
$token = 'udctff3sq02h1d90e44xr3nk282khabt';
$wsdlUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento2/soap/default?wsdl&services=configurableProductLinkManagementV1';
$opts = ['http'=> ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " .$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient  = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$result = $soapClient->configurableProductLinkManagementV1addChild(array('sku' => 'sampleconfigurable','childsku'=>'samplesimpleproduct'));
?>
```

Comment: Show your Json content.

Comment: i am adding like this $result = $soapClient->configurableProductLinkManagementV1addChild(array('sku' => 'sampleconfigurable','childsku'=>'samplesimpleproduct'));

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$wsdlurl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento2/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=configurableProductLinkManagementV1';
$token = '<your_tokne>';
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
//$arguments =
$serviceArgs = array(
    'sku' => 'configurable01',
    'childSku' => 'blue01',

);


$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$result = $soapClient->configurableProductLinkManagementV1addChild($serviceArgs);
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($result); 
?>
```

Comment: i tried but it's not working

Comment: @shivashankarm still got same error?

Comment: yes i am getting same error

Comment: can u share you full code?

Comment: i shared my code

Comment: @shivashankarm Let me check and u know

Comment: Updates ans pls check and let me know. It is working fine my end

Comment: have u put your configurable sku & simple sku ?

Comment: $serviceArgs = array(
    'sku' => '<configurable product sku here>',
    'childSku' => '<simple product sku here>',

);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70660/discussion-between-shivashankar-m-and-abdul).